# Jquery 's dialog strange behaviours for first time only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery dialog in my application. and i am using below function to initialize it.

```
$searchApplianceDialog = $('#divSearchAppliance')
                            .load('job/searchAppliance.jsp', function() {
                            })
                            .dialog(
                                    {
                                        autoOpen : false,
                                        resizable : false,
                                        draggable : false,
                                        modal : true,
                                        title : ' Search Appliance',
                                        width : 850,
                                        open : function() {
                                            $('#searchApplianceApplianceNumber').focus();

                                            resetApplianceSearch("#applianceList",'Link.do?method=searchJobOrderAppliance&showBlank=true','#frmApplianceSearch');

                                                                                    },
                                        beforeClose : function() {
                                        },
                                        close : function() {
                                            $('#searchApplianceButton').focus();
                                        }
                                    }); // ends search appliance
```

when i first open it using

```
$searchApplianceDialog.dialog('open');
```

it is opened but it creates a problem of positioning itself for first time only . it positions itself correctly in the center of the page with reference to page width but with reference to page height it positioned -20 for y axis and this is only for first time , after every time it gets positioned correctly.

**what would be the solution ?**

Comment: More details are required to understand the problem. I personally don't like to use `jQuery.load` because JavaScript code from the loaded page will be executed too (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution)). I can imagine that the reason of the described problem is *outside of the code which you posted*. So I you can be sure that the problem like this will be solved only if you provide URL to the working example or if you would provide the demo in http://jsfiddle.net/. In any way you should post the response from `'job/searchAppliance.jsp'`.

Comment: Sorry for delay Mr. Oleg I will post the link here of live example, tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

try putting that after

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: it is already in ready block.and i have five different dialogs in this page , every dialog works fine only this mentioned creates problems for first time.

Comment: maybe something with the height of an element being auto? cause it used to happen with me. with auto width or height my elements used to act strange at first. sorry cant help u much further.

Comment: so does it mean that i should change height to some fixed value instead of auto ?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have to much time to test your code, but for the experience since I use it so much. Found the thing likes this maybe. When the dialog there is no data in it and then ajax gets data from server and set it to the dialog, it change the size of dialog, I had this kind of problem. So You should add the open() to the load successful function. and another thing is that you didn't add any code to the close function, so it doesn't actually be removed.

Comment: Hello dear i don't understand what you mean ? can you better explain me example and code snippets ?